# $\sin(nx)$ formula derivation using multi-angle formulas

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin(A+B)$ and $\cos(A+B)$ can be used to derive the $\sin(nx)$ formula that is a product of $\sin$ and $\cos$ powers summing to $n$.

> I have seen no derivation using multi-angle anywhere on the internet.
> https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/
> Under generalized expansions that's interesting but proof missing.
> Then that can be used to derive $\sin(nx)$.

Comment: do these links help? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html    https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/

Comment: @C Squared  you misunderstood my question not using eulers or demoivres formulas just sin(a+b)=sinacosb+cosasinb and cos(a+b) equations to get sin(a+a+a..) which is sin(nx)

Comment: https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/

Comment: @Minikute Use induction directly, or write the sum of angle identities in 2D [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) form, then use the properties of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

The probable reason you haven't seen a proof using angle addition formulae is because it's a lot easier to prove directly using expansions of $e^{inx}$. But if you want to do it, you could apply induction - but you have to prove the expansions of $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ at the same time. Here's the start of the proof, the details are left as an exercise:

**Aim:** To prove that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$\begin{eqnarray}\sin(nx) & = & \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r + 1 \leq 1}} (-1)^r {n \choose 2r + 1} \cos^{n - 2r - 1}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x) \\
\cos(nx) & = &  \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r \leq n}} (-1)^r {n \choose 2r} \cos^{n - 2r}(x) \sin^{2r}(x)
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Base case:** For $n = 1$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r + 1 \leq n}} (-1)^r {n \choose 2r + 1} \cos^{n - 2r - 1}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x) & = & \sum_{r = 0}^0 (-1)^r {1 \choose 2r + 1} \cos^{1 - 2r - 1}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x) \\
& = & (-1)^0 {1 \choose 1} \cos^0(x) \sin^1(x) \\
& = & \sin(x)
\end{eqnarray}$$

and similarly for $\cos(x)$.

**Inductive case:** Assume that the statement is true for some $n = k$. Then for $n = k+1$:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \sin((k + 1)x) & = & \sin(kx) \cos(x) \cos(kx) \sin(x) \\
& = & \left( \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r + 1 \leq k}} (-1)^r {k \choose 2r + 1} \cos^{k - 2r - 1}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x) \right) \cos(x) \\ && + \left( \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r \leq k}} (-1)^r {k \choose 2r} \cos^{k - 2r}(x) \sin^{2r}(x) \right) \sin(x) \\
& = & \left(\sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r + 1 \leq k}} (-1)^r {k \choose 2r + 1} \cos^{k - 2r}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x)\right) \\ && + \left( \sum_{\substack{r = 0 \\ 2r \leq k}} (-1)^r {k \choose 2r} \cos^{k - 2r}(x) \sin^{2r + 1}(x) \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

and then you can combine those two sums, being careful with the limits of summation, and applying some results about adding combinations together, and you should get the right expression, and then you can do the same thing for $\cos((k+1)x)$.

The proof via complex numbers, however, is (a) shorter and (b) can be adjusted to work for more general values of $n$ through a [generalized binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations).

Comment: what about without induction using expansion n seeing the pattern. @conman